# I do not see the results of the VBA code in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a VBA code in Access. But, a table or a query does not added to the access. I do not see the results of the VBA code in access.

```
Option Compare Database
Sub TransformX1()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "TRANSFORM Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS SumOfTON " & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT BAR1.[MABD], Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS [Total Of TON] " & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM BAR1 " & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((BAR1.[MABD])<1300) AND ((BAR1.[MAGH])<1300) AND ((BAR1.G)=1)) " & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "GROUP BY BAR1.[MABD] " & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "PIVOT BAR1.[MAGH];"
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You're just opening a recordset and doing nothing with it.

Comment: I want to see the results of the query. Is there a command to save the results of the query? Thank you very much.

Comment: Be specific! Do you wish to insert the results in a table? Or do you just wish to create a query? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Insert the results in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Since your SQL is static, there is no reason to (re)create it in VBA.

Create a query and paste your SQL into this. This will be a crosstab query.

Save it using a name, say, Q1.

Now, create a new query, say Q2, where you use Q1 as source. Adjust query Q2 to be either an *append query* or a *create table query*. This query you can run (execute) at any time.